# Count records using Date filter related tables SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, powerbi

I'm trying to calculates the number of reports (*report_user table*) per user between two date (*Calendar table*) and by day worked (*agenda_user table*).

Here is the diagram of my tables:

[image]

Calendar table :

```
 DATE         Year       Month
---------------------------------
2020-01-01      2020      1
2020-01-02      2020      1
2020-01-03      2020      1
2020-01-04      2020      1
```

AGENDA_USER table :

```
ID_USER        DATE         Value
---------------------------------
1           2020-01-01       1
2           2020-01-01       1
1           2020-01-02       0
2           2020-01-02       1
```

User table :

```
ID_USER        Name     
-------------------------
1              Jack
2              Robert
```

Report_Result table :

```
ID_USER        Date          Result
-----------------------------------
1             2020-01-01      good
1             2020-01-01      good
2             2020-01-01      bad
2             2020-01-01      good
2             2020-01-02      good
2             2020-01-02      good
```

Result I'm trying to find with an SQL query

```
ID_USER        Date          Number of report     Day work      report/work
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1             2020-01-01            2                1               2/1 = 2
2             2020-01-01            2                1                1
1             2020-01-02            0                0                0
2             2020-01-02            2                1                2
```

```
SELECT 
    REPORT_USER.ID_USER, 
    COUNT(ID_USER) AS result
FROM [DB].[dbo].REPORT_USER AS report,
JOIN [DB].[dbo].[USER] AS [USER]
     ON [USER].ID_USER = report.ID_USER
JOIN [DB].[dbo].AGENDA_USER AS agenda
     ON agenda.ID_USER = report.ID_USER
WHERE CAST(agenda.[Date] AS DATE) >= '2020-09-01'
    AND CAST(agenda.[Date] AS DATE) <= '2021-07-28'
    AND [USER].ID_user = 1167
GROUP BY 
    report.ID_VENDEUR;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work? What is the logic to achieve your expected results? What is your question here? There's no clear question or problem statement (about your code you've not shared) in your "question".  [so] isn't a free coding service; don't treat it like one.

Comment: FYI, yes `CAST({ColumnName} AS date)` *is* SARGable, but it [isn't a good idea](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34047/140734). Use `>=`and `<`logic.

Comment: Break your goal into pieces. What does "number of report" mean? Is it the total count of all rows in report_user for a given period / user? Does the value in result column affect the count? Write the query that does that correctly. THEN repeat for "day work" - what is the formula? What logic do you need to calculate that. I think you will need to outer join in some fashion but don't quite understand your goal.

Comment: @Larnu the problem I encounter is that I can't link the date in the agenda_user table with the date in the report_result table

Comment: Why not? What's wrong with joining on the `date` columns?

Comment: @SMor yes sorry , the total count of all rows in report_user for a given period / user ; non the value in result column dont affect the count

Comment: @Larnu Its possible to join table with ID_USER and DATE ?

Comment: They are clearly not the same data type, @SoufianeS , so no. But your data clearly has multiple `date` columns which are the `date` data type (making it all the more confusing that you are casting the value to a `date` in the `WHERE`).

Comment: What purpose does Agenda serve, is it like hours worked or something similar? If an employee has a missing or zero value for a day, can he have reports? Does Agenda filter the data in any way? Also, it would help if your example tables were a bit larger (more rows, not font).

Comment: @RobertSheahan yes agenda is like if user work or not ( filed Value : 0 = user didn't work ; 1=user worked ) ; on a given period between two dates I try to know how many reports the user has made and then divide by the day worked for the same period

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your problem, but I think I'm reasonably close so here is a start, point out my invalid assumptions and we can refine. More data, particularly in Agenda and Reports would really help. An explanation is below (plus see the comment in the code).

The overall flow is to generate a list of days/people you want to report on (cteUserDays), generate a list of how many reports each user generated on each date (cteReps), generate a list of who worked on what days (cteWork), and then JOIN all 3 parts together using a LEFT OUTER JOIN so the report covers all workers on all days.
EDIT: Add cteRepRaw where DATETIME is converted to DATE and "bad" reports are filtered out. Grouping and counting still happens in cteReps, but joining to cteUserDays is not there because it was adding 1 to count if there was a NULL.

```
DECLARE @Cal TABLE (CalDate DATETIME, CalYear int, CalMonth int)
DECLARE @Agenda TABLE (UserID int, CalDate DATE, AgendaVal int)
DECLARE @User TABLE (UserID int, UserName nvarchar(50))
DECLARE @Reps TABLE (UserID int, CalDate DATETIME, RepResult nvarchar(50))

INSERT INTO @Cal(CalDate, CalYear, CalMonth)
VALUES ('2020-01-01', 2020, 1), ('2020-01-02', 2020, 1), ('2020-01-03', 2020, 1), ('2020-01-04', 2020, 1)

INSERT INTO @Agenda(UserID, CalDate, AgendaVal)
VALUES (1, '2020-01-01', 1), (2, '2020-01-01', 1), (1, '2020-01-02', 0), (2, '2020-01-02', 1)

INSERT INTO @User (UserID , UserName )
VALUES (1, 'Jack'), (2, 'Robert')

INSERT INTO @Reps (UserID , CalDate , RepResult )
VALUES (1, '2020-01-01', 'good'), (1, '2020-01-01', 'good')
    , (2, '2020-01-01', 'bad'), (2, '2020-01-01', 'good')
    , (2, '2020-01-02', 'good'), (2, '2020-01-02', 'good')


; with cteUserDays as (
    --First, you want zeros in your table where no reports are, so build a table for that
    SELECT CONVERT(DATE, D.CalDate) as CalDate --EDIT add CONVERT here
      , U.UserID FROM @Cal as D CROSS JOIN @User as U
    WHERE D.CalDate >= '2020-01-01' AND D.CalDate <= '2021-07-28'
    --EDIT Watch the <= date here, a DATE is < DATETIME with hours of the same day
), cteRepRaw as (--EDIT Add this CTE to convert DATETIME to DATE so we can group on it
    --Map the DateTime to a DATE type so we can group reports from any time of day
    SELECT R.UserID 
        , CONVERT(DATE, R.CalDate) as CalDate --EDIT add CONVERT here
        , R.RepResult
    FROM @Reps as R 
    WHERE R.RepResult='good' --EDIT Add this test to only count good ones
), cteReps as (
    --Get the sum of all reports for a given user on a given day, though some might be missing (fill 0)
    SELECT R.UserID , R.CalDate , COUNT(*) as Reports --SUM(COALESCE(R.RepResult, 0)) as Reports
    FROM cteRepRaw as R--cteUserDays as D 
        --Some days may have no reports for that worker, so use a LEFT OUTER JOIN
        --LEFT OUTER JOIN cteRepRaw as R on D.CalDate = R.CalDate AND D.UserID = R.UserID
    GROUP BY R.UserID , R.CalDate 
) , cteWork as (
    --Unclear what values "value" in Agenda can take, but assuming it's some kind of work 
    -- unit, like "hours worked" or "shifts" so add them up 
    SELECT A.UserID , A.CalDate, SUM(A.AgendaVal) as DayWork FROM @Agenda as A 
    WHERE A.CalDate >= '2020-01-01' AND A.CalDate <= '2021-07-28'
    GROUP BY A.CalDate, A.UserID 
) 
SELECT D.UserID , D.CalDate, COALESCE(R.Reports, 0) as Reports, W.DayWork 
    --NOTE: While it's probably a mistake to credit a report to a day a worker had
    --no shifts, it could happen and would throw an error so check
    , CASE WHEN W.DayWork > 0 THEN R.Reports / W.DayWork ELSE 0 END as RepPerWork
FROM cteUserDays as D 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cteReps as R on D.CalDate=R.CalDate AND R.UserID = D.UserID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cteWork as W on D.UserID = W.UserID AND D.CalDate = W.CalDate 
ORDER BY CalDate , UserID
```

First, as per the comments in your OP "Agenda" represents when the user is working, you don't say how it's structured so I'll assume it can have multiple entries for a given person on a given day (i.e. a 4 hour shift and an 8 hour shift) so I'll add them up to get total work (cteWork). I also assume that if somebody didn't work, you can't have a report for them. I check for this, but normally I'd expect your data validator to pre-screen those out.

Second, I'll assume reports are 1 per record, and a given user can have multiple per day. You have that in your given, but it's important to this solution so I'm restating in case somebody else reads this later.

Third, I assume you want all days reported for all users, I assure this by generating a CROSS join between users and days (cteUserDays)

Comment: thanks man for your time and help i'm close to the result. the count result doesn't work 

I need to adjust the date in the reports and calendar table because they are in DateTime format while the agenda is in Date format?

Comment: OK @SoufianeS I tweaked it to convert dates, and I fixed the count being off from incorrectly counting NULLs, try this out and let me know if it's right now.

Comment: it works !  thanks so much for your precious help :)